# Bootstrap 4 row is not adjusting its height accroding to Slick.js slide height

Tags: bootstrap-4, slick.js

I am trying to make a Slick.js slider parent and thumb navigator. As shown in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/LYZJxwZ) demo, each slide has different height which varies according to the content inside the container. My expectation is, the row with bg-dark should adjust its height because Slick is changing its height according to the content but that's not happening.

```js
    $(".profile-slider").slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1, 
      arrows: false,
      centerMode:true,
      dots: false,
      fade: true,
    });
      
    $(".thumbnail-slider").slick({
      asNavFor: ".profile-slider", 
      dots: true,
      infinite: true, 
      slidesToShow: 10, 
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      variableWidth: true, 
      arrows: false,
      focusOnSelect: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by using the setting `adaptiveHeight: true`. Also, you do not need to set `centerMode` if you're only showing one slide at a time.

```js
$(".profile-slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1, 
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  fade: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, it wasn't documented in the slickJS documentation so I couldn't figure out.